# Lightning component : send a map as parameter for calling apex method, in javascript controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

In the javascript controller of my lightning component, I need to call an apex method and pass it a map as parameter.

I have issues when setting the value in the map, in the javascript.

Now I have something like this in the javascript controller :

```
handleGetResult : function(component, event, helper) {
    var lines = component.get('v.listLines');
    console.log('lines : ');
    console.log(lines);

    //send a map as a parameter of the apex method
    var mapLines = {};
    for(var key in lines.keys()){
         mapLines[key] = lines.get(key);
    }

    console.log('mapLines : ');
    console.log(mapLines);

    //call apex method that construct the query
    var action = component.get('c.manageFilters');
    action.setParams({
        lines : mapLines
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS"){

        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

But here `mapLines` is null even if I put many item in it via the lightning component. `lines` is not null and contains all the items.

I don't know how to create the map in javascript.

The apex method so far :

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String manageFilters(Map<String, Object> lines){
    System.debug('### lines : ' + lines);

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it this way:

```
var lines = component.get('v.listLines');
console.log('lines : ', lines);

//send a map as a parameter of the apex method
var mapLines = {};
for(var i=0; i<lines.length;i++ ){
    mapLines[i] = lines[i];
}

console.log('mapLines : ', mapLines);
```

Below is the log output that I got from my test:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code ,

```
 var mapToSend = {}
  for (var key of lines.keys()) {
      mapToSend[key] = lines.get(key);
  }
  console.log('map tosend:::', mapToSend);
  action.setParams({
      lines: mapToSend
  });
```

Apex class:

```
 @AuraEnabled
 public static void manageFilters(Map<String, Object> lines ){
System.debug(JSON.serialize(lines )); }
```